# PyQt - How to close database connection on class destruction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyqt

If my class uses a database quite a few times (a lot of functions/properties use data from the DB), what's the best practice: to create a DB connection once at the start of the class, do whatever so many times, and then close the DB connection on exit (using global variables); or to create/use/close DB connections in every property (using local variables)?

If it's better to start a connection once and close it on class destruction, how can I do this?

```
def __del__ (self)
    self.connection.close()
```

doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`__del__` function is only called when the object get destructed which is when no object is referencing it anymore while garbage collecting is occurring.

Either see what object is still referencing your class when you let it go or implement an explicit shutdown method on your class.

It can be dangerous to rely on the `__del__` method to release resources because of object not being destructed when we think it is.

From python documentation

> Some objects contain references to “external” resources such as open files or windows. It is understood that these resources are freed when the object is garbage-collected, but since garbage collection is not guaranteed to happen, such objects also provide an explicit way to release the external resource, usually a close() method. Programs are strongly recommended to explicitly close such objects. The ‘try...finally‘ statement provides a convenient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If another classes will also use database connections then you can create a class that will include methods  for creating db, connecting/closing db and retrieving information from db, etc and then inherit this class.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database close-request function that can be accessed by the main window class.

You can then call this within the window's [`closeEvent`](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent), and perhaps take different actions depending on the function's return value.

Comment: Having GUI code know about, and act on the DB is bad software design.

Comment: @EricFortin. In what way(s), specifically?

Comment: MVC is a widely accepted design pattern. I'm ok with hooking on the closeEvent but not with accessing the DB directly within it.

Comment: @EricFortin. Okay, thanks. I can see my answer was probably poorly worded, as I didn't really mean to suggest direct DB access. Hopefully, my revised answer is less controversial.